# Handling SERIRQ Interrupts from LPC-Connected Devices

Tags: linux, device-driver

How are SERIRQ interrupts generated by devices connected via an LPC (Low Pin Count) bus handled by Linux device drivers? In particular, how is an interrupt generated by one device on the bus differentiated from an interrupt generated by another device on the bus?

Answer (score 3):

SERIRQ serially encodes the IRQ number.  From a software/OS standpoint, LPC serial interrupts are no different than legacy ISA interrupts.